# Does anyone know of unusual and fun chess tournaments around the world?

Tags: tournament

I have heard of [this tournament](https://echiquier-medocain.fr/open-des-vins-2018/) in France, where the winners receive prizes in wine.
Now I was wondering if there are any other unusual or funny chess tournaments around the world? If yes, which can you recommend or where could one find a list of them?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are lots of chess *variants* for which tournaments are/were organized, e.g. for [Condi Chess](https://www.google.com/search?q=condi+chess&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) on the [La Rochade camping](http://campinglarochade.free.fr/Sommerprogramm%202009.html) in France. I fear the question will be very broad if you allow those.

Answer (score 8):

The [Chess Train](https://praguechess.cz/poradane-akce-detail.php?id_akce=43&langue=en) tournament is an 11-round rapid tournament that is held on a moving train. In five days it travels from Prague to Prague, visiting different cities each day. This year it goes to Poland, including Warsaw and Krakow.

Each day the train travel is from 10:00 to 14:00, with the two rounds of rapid during that time; the afternoon and evening are then free for sightseeing.

Answer (score 5):

Please don't miss the [Underwater Chess Tournament](https://www.wthr.com/article/london-hosts-underwater-chess-championship) in London :

https://www.cnews.fr/videos/france/2018-08-26/une-partie-dechecs-sous-leau-792169

Here is a short [video](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=299361017539491&id=107637365950776) of the competition.

Answer (score 4):

This one, held by the Marshall Chess Club in New York City, might fit:

> New Year’s Ridiculousness Insane Person Championship!
>   15-SS, G/25 d5. $1,432 Gtd: $499-222-77-76-1, U2287: $164, U1974: $144, U1626: $131. Idiocy Prize: $118 to player scoring best in tournament with 1.g4 and/or 1…g5. EF: $45; Non-MCC Mbr: Additional $25 Mbr fee. GMs Free, $39 reduced from prizes. (Re-entry: $29.99.) Reg: 11:15-11:45am. Rds: 12-1:15-2:30-4:15-5:30pm each day. Max 5 byes, request at entry. Proper attire appreciated. Register online: www.marshallchessclub.org/register. 23 W 10th St / NYC / 212-477-3716.
>   When
>   Sun Dec 30, 2018 12pm – Tue Jan 1, 2019 8pm Eastern Time

Comment: The great thing with this tournament is that it requires "Proper attire appreciated" for a "Ridiculousness Insane Person Championship".